# unable to send a combination of keybord commands in watir

Tags: cucumber, watir

I have a step definition:

```
Then (/^I send '(.?*)' keys$/) do |key|
  $browser.send_keys key
end
```

I pass `:shift,:tab` in my feature file.  This doesn't work for me.

But when I have a step definition

```
Then (/^I send keys$/) do
  key =:shift,:tab
  $browser.send_keys key
end
```

and hard code the value, it works fine. What might be the issue?

Comment: Not sure if a comment on keyboard shortcuts belongs here.

Comment: Is the problem that the Cucumber step is not being found or that Watir is not sending the right key combination. Assuming the problem is the latter, it would help to show the entire step definition.

Comment: Adding both the step definitions:                                                'Then (/^I send '(.?*)' keys$/) do |key|
 $browser.send_keys key
end  '                                                                                                                                                      'Then (/^I send keys$/) do
   key =:shift,:tab
   $browser.send_keys key
end'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The problem is that when Cucumber gives you the `key` (in the first step definition), it is a string with value ':shift,:tab'. Watir just sees this as text and therefore types each of those characters (rather than interpreting the special keys).

In contrast, the second step definition the `key` is an array containing 2 symbols.

You need to take the string from the Cucumber step and manipulate it to be symbols.

**Solution**

Depending on the different sequence of keys you need to send, the following step definition might be sufficient:

```
Then (/^I send '(.?*)' keys$/) do |key|
  key_sequence = key.split(',').map do |key|
    if key[0] == ':'
      key[1..-1].to_sym
    else
      key
    end
  end

  $browser.send_keys key_sequence 
end
```

This step will:

1. Take the string ':shift,:tab' (from the step)
2. Split the string on commas, which is assumed to separate the keys
3. If the key starts with a colon, assume it is a special character and convert it to a symbol.
4. If the key does not start with a colon, assume it is plain text and leave it as-is.
5. Send the mapped keys to the `send_keys` method.